# defining page titles specifically

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo out dynamic php titles depends on page for seo purposes.

I successfully did this the pages I call from database depends on their id's.

Like that:

```
if (isset($_GET["category_id"])) {
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = ".$_GET['category_id']." ");
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
  $title = $r["title"];

  }
}
```

And this is how I echo out:

```
<title><?php if (isset($_GET["category_id"])) { echo $title; echo " |"; } ?> mypage.com</title>
```

result:

on `category.php?category_id=1` Page title is: "Category 1 | mypage.com"

*

But there are pages which is not static.

for example: `index.php`, `login.php`.

*

I want to figure out how to edit my code below to print `"Login"`  on `login.php` between title tags.

```
<title>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["category_id"])) { 
echo $title; echo " |"; 
} 
?> mypage.com
</title>
```

**EDIT**

my `login.php` is like that:

```
include("header.php");

content.
```

So I need to define `$title` for `login.php` in `header.php`

I need to add some codes to `header.php` when user will see different title on `login.php`, `index.php` etc.

I'm able to do it `category.php?category?id=1` already with the code above, but I need to also make it for `login.php`, `index.php` and so on.

Comment: set `$title`. To be honest, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Do you mean to echo login not login.php..<code>echo str_replace(".php","","login.php")<code>You can change login.php with your variable..

Comment: You really should use a single point of entry for your app.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this within the code you outlined.

First, I'm going to simplify some of your code a bit. This also potentially makes it slightly faster:

```
echo "<title>$title | mypage.com</title>";
```

This assumes that $title is going to be set, either by the query from when $_GET['category_id'] is set, or from the file that calls it. The great thing about includes is that they can pass variables. So in the login.php and any other file where you are not doing a GET, just specify $title in that file.

Login.php:

```
$title = 'Login';
include("header.php");

content.
```

Which would display page title of "Login | mypage.com".